# Can I convert an internal user into LDAP user in Foreman?

Tags: ldap, authentication, foreman

I've got several users set up in Foreman 1.9, and I've just enabled LDAP authentication. I can get a new user logged in, but lots of machines are owned by older users, and there is editing history for the provisioning templates. Is there any way (happy to edit the database if necessary) to change the authentication on these existing users to be via LDAP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, go to **Administer > Users**, click on any user and modify the **Authorized by** field. You can't modify your own authentication source though. See an example below:

[image: admin > users in the UI]

Comment: That was the key piece of information - you can't change your own!